# Noise through speaker with respect to varying frequency using Tkinter sliders

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a beginner in coding python. I'm trying to create square wave sound through the speaker with respect to varying frequency.
I have the code which generates noise with respect to frequency and also tkinter slider code. 
I want to know how to merge both these codes so that I can change the frequency of the noise using the slider.

Code 1

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
from Tkinter import *

def audio(p):
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

volume = 0.5     # range [0.0, 1.0]
fs = 44100       # sampling rate, Hz, must be integer
duration = 1.0   # in seconds, may be float
f=440            # sine frequency, Hz, may be float

# generate samples, note conversion to float32 array
samples = (np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(fs*duration)*f/fs)).astype(np.float32)

# for paFloat32 sample values must be in range [-1.0, 1.0]
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                channels=1,
                rate=fs,
                output=True)

# play. May repeat with different volume values (if done interactively) 
stream.write(volume*samples)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

p.terminate()

master = Tk()
w = Scale(master, from_=0, to=42, command=audio)
w.pack()


mainloop()
```

Code 2

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()  
w = Scale(master, from_=0, to=42)
w.pack()
w = Scale(master, from_=0, to=200, orient=HORIZONTAL)   
w.pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your audio-generating code into a subprogram. Set the `command` for the `Scale` to run the audio procedure. E.g `w = Scale(master, from_=0, to=42, command=audio)`, where `audio` takes the parameter of the frequency `f`.

Comment: How to make f as a variable and connect it to the slider.

Comment: The `Scale` will automatically pass `f` to `audio` when it calls it.

Comment: Sorry, as am a beginner am not getting. Please help me with the above program by altering it by yourself.